# tried to connect a ModelForm

Tags: python, django

i am reciving a "value error"
because of "ModelForm has no model class specified."

i tried to check the : models.py forms.py and views.py but all looks pretty good for me

views.py :

```
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
   login_url='/login/'
   redirect_field_name='Myblog/post_detail.html'
   form_class = PostForm
   model = Post
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   text = models.TextField()
   created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
   class meta:
       model = Post
       fields = ('author','title','text')
```

from app.urls.py
url(r'^post/new/$',views.CreatePostView.as_view(),name='post_new'),

Comment: Can you show the *full* traceback?

Comment: Note, you can set the `fields` tuple directly on the view class, so you don't need to define a form at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Meta`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelforms-overriding-default-fields) is with an **uppercase**, according to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) the names of classes all start with an uppercase. In your form, you should write:

```
# app/forms.py

class PostForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('author','title','text')
```

Since you wrote it as `meta`, Django indeed did not understand what `model` you were using.

If you however do not write a form with specific items, you can - like [@DanielRoseman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56401528/tried-to-connect-a-modelform/56401547#comment99401621_56401528) says, just define this at the [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView):

```
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url='/login/'
    redirect_field_name='Myblog/post_detail.html'
    model = Post
    fields = ('author', 'title', 'text')
```

Django can construct a form class through the [**`modelform_factory`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/models/#modelform-factory).